# Sound waves travelling in air and the amount of air affected by the wave

Tags: waves, acoustics

1. If there is a sound wave travelling in the air, will the amount of air transported by the wave be proportional to the intensity?

Here is my answer: yes, because as the energy of the wave is related to the square of the amplitude of oscillations, the more energy you have, the more the wave will be able to travel further and the more amount of air will be affected. My teacher said this is wrong and gave me 0. Why?

2. Is the amplitude independent of the wavelength and frequency?

Here is my answer: yes, the wave speed in the medium determines wavelenght and frequency, but amplitude is separate. I got half points for this one.

What is wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean transversal displacement of air? Is sound not longitudinal?

Comment: Wow, that was very stupid of me. Sorry! Forget I said anything

Comment: No other leads?

Comment: For 1, how does the air move as the sound wave propagates?  Does this result in transport of the air?

Comment: It comes back and forth. But would that not be still considered transportation as it still moves but its "overall displacement would sum up to zero"?